# What does the eye over a hero mean in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When playing Heroes of the Storm, sometimes I see a blue eyeball or a red eyeball pop up above the names of one of my teammates:
[image: Eye icon over a player's name]

My guess is the eye has something to do with heroes being visible (with the red eye meaning the enemy team can see me), but I have no idea what the blue eye means.

What does the eye actually indicate?

Comment: Do you play for blue when you see that blue eye?? If you play for red than it should mean that blue team sees you.

Comment: I was pretty sure I saw both colors during the same match. Will need to check again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- **Blue Eye**: When you are in a bush and enemy team doesn't see you.
- **Red Eye**: When you are in a bush or cloaked (Nova/Zeratul or Ally Tyrande's [Shadowstalk](http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/wiki/abilities/shadowstalk)) **and** enemy team sees you through abilities like [Tyrande's Shadowstalk](http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/wiki/abilities/shadowstalk), [Clairvoyance talent](http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/wiki/talents/talent-clairvoyance), [Tassadar's Oracle](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Tassadar#Skills) or similar.

Comment: Does it also show a blue eye if an invisible enemy is next to you?

Comment: @heinrich5991 Yes I believe so. I think the only real way to know an invisible enemy is next to you in the brush is if you run into them or reveal with an ability (skillshot, clairvoyance etc).

Answer (score 3):

Blue eye means that enemy team don't see you right now.